# Change number of cells in raster using GDAL?

Tags: raster, gdal, merge

i have 5 raster files and i want to merge them to one file with exact 50x50 cells because i have an R script to process it later.

I tried the ArcGIS function "mosaic to raster" but it delivers a raster with 70x107 cells and seems not to have any options for entering the number of cells.

Is there any possible way to transform it from 70x107 to 50x50 cells?

Comment: Do you have set up Environmets in ArcGIS? Like use Snap raster and Cell Size to have exactly same output as input? See this link: http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Snap_Raster/001w0000000m000000/

Comment: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html `gdal_translate -outsize 50 50`

Comment: thank you very much user30184 !    result<-gdal_translate(src_dataset="inputName.tif",dst_dataset="outputNmae.tif",outsize=c(50,50)) was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: @user30184 - You should post your comment as an answer buddy :)

Comment: @Joseph, my comment is both low-quality and off-topic as an answer because it is too short and fits only with "raster" but no other tags :)

Comment: @user30184 So that the asker has something to accept (just a couple of lines should be fine), I have retrofitted the question title, tags and body to the comment in which the asker indicates that GDAL provides the answer being sought.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the size of the output raster explicitly with the GDAL utility program "gdal_translate" http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html. A complete command which should work for you is.

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -outsize 50 50 input.tif output_resized.tif
```

I suggest to read and think about the other parameters of gdal_translate as well. For example using -r switch for selecting some other resampling method than the default "nearest" may suit better for your further processing.